# Why is this Go code the equivalent speed as that of Python (and not much faster)?

Tags: performance, go, checksum

I need to calculate sha256 checksums for files over 1GB (read file by chunks), currently I am using python with this:

```py
import hashlib
import time

start_time = time.time()


def sha256sum(filename="big.txt", block_size=2 ** 13):
    sha = hashlib.sha256()
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(block_size), b''):
           sha.update(chunk)
    return sha.hexdigest()

input_file = '/tmp/1GB.raw'
print 'checksum is: %s\n' % sha256sum(input_file)
print 'Elapsed time: %s' % str(time.time() - start_time)
```

I wanted to give a try to [golang](http://golang.org) thinking I could get faster results, but after trying the following code, it runs a couple of seconds slower:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha256"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "math"
    "os"
    "time"
)   

const fileChunk = 8192

func File(file string) string {
    fh, err := os.Open(file)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }   

    defer fh.Close()

    stat, _ := fh.Stat()
    size := stat.Size()
    chunks := uint64(math.Ceil(float64(size) / float64(fileChunk)))
    h := sha256.New()

    for i := uint64(0); i < chunks; i++ {
        csize := int(math.Min(fileChunk, float64(size-int64(i*fileChunk))))
        buf := make([]byte, csize)
        fh.Read(buf)
        io.WriteString(h, string(buf))
    }   

    return fmt.Sprintf("%x", h.Sum(nil))
}   

func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    fmt.Printf("checksum is: %s\n", File("/tmp/1G.raw"))
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Printf("Elapsed time: %s\n", elapsed)
}
```

Any idea how to improve the [golang](http://golang.org) code if possible? maybe to use all computer CPU cores, one for reading and other for hashing, any ideas ?

## Update

As suggested I am using this code:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    fh, err := os.Open("/tmp/1GB.raw")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer fh.Close()

    h := sha256.New()
    _, err = io.Copy(h, fh)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil)))

    fmt.Printf("Elapsed time: %s\n", time.Since(start))
}
```

For testing I am creating the 1GB file with this:

```
# mkfile 1G /tmp/1GB.raw
```

The new version is faster but not that much, what about using channels? could the use of more than one CPU/core could help to improve? I was expecting to have an improvement of at least 20% but unfortunately I am getting almost no gain, is almost nothing.

time result for python

```
 5.867u 0.250s 0:06.15 99.3%    0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
```

time results for go after compiling (go build) and executing the binary:

```
 5.687u 0.198s 0:05.93 98.9%    0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
```

Any more ideas?

## test results

Using the version using channels posted below on the accepted answer by @icza

```
Elapsed time: 5.894779733s
```

Using the version with **no** channels:

```
Elapsed time: 5.823489239s
```

I thought that using channels would increase a little bit but seems to not.

I am running this on a MacBook Pro OS X Yosemite. using go version:

```
go version go1.4.1 darwin/amd64
```

## update 2

Setting runtime.GOMAXPROCS to 4:

```
runtime.GOMAXPROCS(4)
```

Made things faster:

```
Elapsed time: 5.741511748s
```

## update 3

Changing the chunk size to 8192 (like in the python version) give the expected result:

```
...
for b, hasMore := make([]byte, 8192<<10), true; hasMore; {
...
```

Also using only runtime.GOMAXPROCS(2)

Comment: Anyway, I wouldn't expect it to be [much] faster. Most of the work is done in either the IO layers or the hashing layer (efficiently written by someone else, in C for Python): it's not really "Python code" vs "Go code".

Comment: Can you explain the test results? What do the numbers/times mean?

Comment: is the [output of the time](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/time.1.html) command, basically I use time ./checksum or time python checksum.py

Comment: have you tried it with a file that's not all zeros BTW?

Comment: Also, I've ran the code with a couple of other hash functions, and sha512 was twice as fast, md5 x5 faster, and sha1 almost x3 faster.

Comment: md5/sha1/sha256/sha512 (python/go) they give almost the same speed, what did you did to get x2,x3,s5 speeds (thinking that you where using go) ? can you share your code ?

Comment: The python hashlib module uses the system openSSL (if available), so you are not comparing Go and Python. I doubt you can speed up that python code much, if the bottleneck is in the hash calls.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your solution is quite inefficient as you're making new buffers in each iteration, you use them once and you just throw them away.

Also you convert the content of your buffer (`buf`) to `string` and you write that `string` to the sha256 calculator which converts it back to bytes: an absolutely unnecessary round-trip.

Here is another quite fast solution, test this for performance:

```
fh, err := os.Open(file)
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}   
defer fh.Close()

h := sha256.New()
_, err = io.Copy(h, fh)
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}   

fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil)))
```

**A little explanation:**

[`io.Copy()`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy) is a function which will read all the data (until EOF is reached) from a [`Reader`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) and write all those to the specified [`Writer`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer). Since the sha256 calculator ([`hash.Hash`](http://golang.org/pkg/hash/#Hash)) implements `Writer` and the [`File`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#File) (or rather `*File`) implements `Reader`, this is as easy as it can be.

Once all the data has been written to the hash, [`hex.EncodeToString()`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/#EncodeToString) will simply convert the result (obtained by `hash.Sum(nil)`) to a human-readable, hex string.

### Final Verdict

The program reads 1GB of data from the hard disk and does some calculation with it (calculates its SHA-256 hash). Since reading from the hard disk is a relatively slow operation, the performance gain of the Go version will not be significant compared to the Python solution. The overall run takes a couple of seconds which is in the same order of magnitude as the time required to read 1 GB of data from the hard disk. Since both the Go and the Python solution requires approximately the same amount of time to read the data from the disk, you won't see much different results.

### Possibility of Performance Improvements with Multiple Goroutines

There is a slight margin where you can improve performance by reading a chunck of the file into one buffer, start calculating its SHA-256 hash, and at the same time read the next chunck of the file. Once its done, send that to the SHA-256 calculator and at the same time read the next chunk into the first buffer.

But since reading the data from the disk takes more time than calculating its SHA-256 digest (or updating the state of the digest calculator), you won't see significant improvement. The performance bottleneck in your case will always be the time required to read the data into memory.

Here is a complete, runnable solution using 2 goroutines where while 1 goroutine reads a chunk of the file the other calculates hash of a previously read chunk, and when the reading of a goroutine finishes continues with hashing and allowing the other to read in parallel.

Proper synchronization between the phases (reading, hashing) is done with channels. As suspected, the performance gain is just a little over **4% in time** (may vary based on CPU and hard disk speed) because the hashing computation is negligible compared to the disk reading time. The performance gain will most likely be higher if the reading speed of the hard disk is greater (test it on SSD).

So the complete program:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "hash"
    "io"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

const file = "t:/1GB.raw"

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(2) // Important as Go 1.4 uses only 1 by default!

    start := time.Now()

    f, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    h := sha256.New()

    // 2 channels: used to give green light for reading into buffer b1 or b2
    readch1, readch2 := make(chan int, 1), make(chan int, 1)

    // 2 channels: used to give green light for hashing the content of b1 or b2
    hashch1, hashch2 := make(chan int, 1), make(chan int, 1)

    // Start signal: Allow b1 to be read and hashed
    readch1 <- 1
    hashch1 <- 1

    go hashHelper(f, h, readch1, readch2, hashch1, hashch2)

    hashHelper(f, h, readch2, readch1, hashch2, hashch1)

    fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil)))

    fmt.Printf("Elapsed time: %s\n", time.Since(start))
}

func hashHelper(f *os.File, h hash.Hash, mayRead <-chan int, readDone chan<- int, mayHash <-chan int, hashDone chan<- int) {
    for b, hasMore := make([]byte, 64<<10), true; hasMore; {
        <-mayRead
        n, err := f.Read(b)
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                hasMore = false
            } else {
                panic(err)
            }
        }
        readDone <- 1

        <-mayHash
        _, err = h.Write(b[:n])
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        hashDone <- 1
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

In my solution I only used 2 goroutines. There is no point using more because as noted before the disk reading speed is the bottleneck which is already used at its maximum as 2 goroutines will be able to perform reading at any time.

**Notes on synchronization:** 2 goroutines run parallel. Each goroutine is allowed to use its local buffer `b` at any time. Access to the shared `File` and to the shared `Hash` is synchronized by the channels, only 1 goroutine is allowed to use the `Hash` at any given time, and only 1 goroutine is allowed to use (read) from the `File` at any given time.

Comment: If I am right this reads all the file into memory, how to do it more efficiently by reading by chunks?

Comment: @nbari No. `io.Copy()` will not read the whole file into memory, it uses a "small" internal buffer for reading chunks from the source and writing it to the destination. This internal buffer has the size of 32KB ([`io.Copy()` source code](http://golang.org/src/io/io.go?s=12247:12307#L340)).

Comment: @nbari Can you please post your performance results comparing this method to the python solution?

Comment: Updated my answer to include your performance test results and to consider parallel execution.

Comment: Could you please show me how could it be done using channels just for testing?

Comment: @nbari As per your request, I implemented and included a complete, runnable solution for parallel execution using multiple goroutines. My test results are also included, please be so kind and test it yourself and post your results too.

Comment: Many thanks, results on the post,  I thought that using channels would increase a little bit but seems to not.

Comment: @nbari Please run the test multiple times and calculate average as runtime may vary even by 5% between runs!

Comment: I am running this on a macbook pro (maybe can be the issue), but all the time, the initial version show faster results than the one using gorutines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68949/discussion-between-nbari-and-icza).

Comment: @nbari Sorry, chat is blocked for me here. Does your macbook pro has 1 CPU core by any chance? If so or if only 1 CPU core can be used by the test program, that would certainly explain why the solution using multiple goroutines is slower...

Comment: If I am right it has 4, thats what the output of  ``sysctl hw.ncpu`` shows

Comment: @nbari The result of [`runtime.NumCPU()`](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#NumCPU) is what matters. Also try playing with buffer size too. In my example I used 64 KB buffer size (`64<<10`).

Comment: The output of ``sysctl hw.physicalcpu`` gives me  2

Comment: Why you are not using ``io.Copy`` on the 'channels' versions?

Comment: @nbari Because `io.Copy()` does not return until the whole file is sent to the hash calculator hence it would not allow us to read/calculate in parallel, in 2 separate goroutines.

Comment: Many thanks for the code and explanations, after setting the properly chunksize thinks are much faster around .5 seconds faster than when using io.Copy

Answer (score 0):

For someone didn't know, I think this will help.

https://blog.golang.org/pipelines

At the end of this page, there are a solution for md5 files by goroutines.

I try this out on my own "~" dir. use goroutines spend 1.7 second, with out goroutines use 2.8 second.

here is how time use when without goroutines. and I don't know how to calculate time use when using goroutines because all these things runs at the same time.

`time use  2.805522165s
time read file  759.476091ms
time md5   1.710393575s
time sort  17.355134ms`